# Get Profile Key Score for Individual Page in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, analytics, sitecore-dms

I have a question regarding Sitecore Analytics and user profile keys. I need to be able to get the score of a profile key for an individual page. For example, if I have a profile key called "traveler" that could have a value of 1-10 on a given page, I need to be able to get the value for that key that was assigned by the content author. I have found that by using the following:

```cs
Sitecore.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.Current.Data.Profiles.GetProfile("Profile Name").GetProfileKeyValue("traveler")
```

I can get the total score that the user has accumulated throughout their session, but I cannot seem to find a way to get the score just for the current page.

Any insight anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this post is rather old, but for future references a lot has changed in Sitecore.
I do not know if this was possible in 2010, but at least in 2013 there are API methods for extracting the Tracking values of a page.

I would never recommend to manually parse the raw data in in the __Tracking Field.

Here's how to read tracking data for the Persona Profile using the Sitecore Analytics API :

```csharp
public static string ProfileValues(this Item item)
{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        TrackingField trackingField = new TrackingField(item.Fields[Constants.Sitecore.FieldIDs.Tracking]);
        ContentProfile profile = trackingField.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(profileData =>
                                profileData.Name.Equals("Persona") && profileData.IsSavedInField);

        ContentProfileKeyData[] profileKeys = profile.Keys;

        foreach (ContentProfileKeyData profileKey in profileKeys)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:{1};", profileKey.Name, profileKey.Value));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Best Regards
Lasse Rasch

Comment: Agree with this when you are looking at the `__Tracking` field of a single item or a restricted set. However, there are occasions where I think manual parsing is necessary. I recently needed to loop through 50+ items and work with the `__Tracking` field of each. The page load time increased massively (6 or 7 seconds). A little profiling showed that the instantiation of the `TrackingField` class was the culprit. Manual parsing of the field reduced the load time to ~300ms. It seems `TrackingField` has quite an overhead. That said, I would only advocate manual parsing when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found that this is stored as an XML string in a field called `__Tracking` on each item. It can be accessed just like any other data field, using the `Fields` collection. For example:

```cs
Item itemToCheck = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/path to item/");
string trackingXml = itemToCheck.Fields["__Tracking"].ToString();
```

The XML in the string is structured like this:

```xml
<tracking>
    <profile name="profile1">
        <key name="key1" value="1" />
        <key name="key2" value="10" />
    </profile>
    <profile name="profile2">
        <key name="key3" value="12" />
        <key name="key4" value="4" />
    </profile>
</tracking>
```

This string can be converted to an `XmlDocument` and processed using `SelectNodes` like normal